# Retrieving X rows from an ordered CTE, TOP vs Range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, query-performance

**Objective:**

Want to know which is faster/better performance when trying to retrieve a finite number of rows from CTE that is already ordered.

**Example:**

Say I have a CTE(intentionally simplified) that looks like this, and I only want the top 5 rows :

```
WITH    cte
          AS (
               SELECT  Id =  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.ActionID asc)
                      , t.Name
               FROM     tblSample AS t -- tblSample is indexed on Id              
             )
```

[image]

**Which is faster:**

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM cte
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE Id BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ?
```

**Notes:**

1. I am not a DB programmer, so to me the TOP solution seems better as
   once SS finds the 5th row, it will stop executing and "return" (100%
   assumption) while in the other method, i feel it will unnecessarily
   process the whole cte.
2. My question is for a CTE, would the answer to this question be the same if it were a table?

Comment: Did you actually try this? A CTE cannot be ordered...

Comment: @HoneyBadger I simplified the CTE for the question, in my real world-case, the CTE is created using a RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY...) query which inserts the rows ordered by Id

Comment: A CTE doesn't insert rows. A CTE is executed when it is called in the following query. So when you do `select * from cte ...` is when the cte is executed (the whole cte). Filtering doesn't occur till later. I doubt you'll find much performance difference between the two methods.

Comment: I'd presume it is better to use TOP 5 - if you calculate RANK over a million records, then take 1-5, is there a risk the work of sorting all million records will be carried out, instead of simply determining the TOP 5?  You can look at 'query execution plans' for evidence.  If you fave a table which already contains IDs and you want 1-5 then I think if ID is primary key or indexed - it probably doesn't make much difference - the queries are not the same though, if there is not a 1-5 then TOP 5 will return the first 5

Comment: I think you may get a better performance if you define the cte as TOP 5, with an `order by` identical to what you use in the `RANK()`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I see what ur saying, thanks!

Comment: `top 5` without an `order by` on the *same* query is effectively "select 5 arbitrary rows". Any `ORDER BY` applied to a subquery, CTE or within a window function has *no* effect on the order of rows so far as any outer/consuming query is concerned - it's merely used to *define* some other element of the query (here, what `Id` values to *assign*). It does *not* guarantee that the CTE is "sorted" in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Unfortunately the `ORDER BY` in the CTE or subquery can show an effect on the query result depending on the operations performed by the server, thus tricking users into thinking that the query does what they want. So you should rather say that it has "no *deterministic* effect"; an apparently sorted query result is a side-effect that may or may not occur depending on the decisions made by the query optimizer. Very important to mention IMHO because it basically answers the question!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Lucero, I just found this out for myself today experimentally after posting the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to note is that both queries are not going to always produce the same result set. Consider the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblSample (ActionId int not null, name varchar(10) not null);
INSERT #tblSample VALUES (1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb'),(3,'ccc');
```

Both of these will produce the same result:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT id = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.ActionID asc), t.name
  FROM #tblSample t
)
SELECT TOP(2) * FROM CTE;

WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT id = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.ActionID asc), t.name
  FROM #tblSample t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

Now let's do this update:

```
UPDATE #tblSample SET ActionId = 1;
```

After this update the first query still returns two rows, the second query returns 3. Keep in mind too that, without an ORDER BY in the TOP query the results are not guaranteed because there is no default order in SQL.

With that out of the way - which performs better? It depends. It depends on your indexing, your statistics, number of rows, and the execution plan that the SQL Engine goes with.

Answer (score 0):

Top 5 selects any 5 rows as per Index defined on the table whereas Id between 1 and 5 tries to fetch data based on Id column whether by Index seek or scan depends on the selected attributes. Both are two different queries.. 'Id between' query might be slow if you do not have any index on Id,

Let me try to explain with an example...

Consider this is your data..

```
create index nci_name on yourcte(id) include(name)
--drop index nci_name on yourcte

;with cte as (
select * from yourcte )
select top 5 * from cte

;with cte as (
select * from yourcte )
select * from cte where id between 1 and 5
```

First i am creating index on id with name included, Now if you see your second query does Index seek and first one does index scan and selects top 5, so in this case second approach is better

See the execution plan:

[image]

Now i am removing the index
Executing 
    --drop index nci_name on yourtable

Now it does table scan on both the approaches

[image]

If you notice in both the table scans, in the first one it reads only 5 rows and second approach it reads 10 rows and applies predicate

See execution plan properties for first plan

[image]

For second approach it reads 10 rows

[image]

Now first approach is better..

In your case this index needs to be on ActionId which determines the id.

Hence performance depends on how you index on your base table.

Comment: @KannanKandaswamy a CTE cannot have index.

Comment: CTE cannot have index but underlying table has index rite?

Comment: @KannanKandaswamy,   I see what u mean based on HoneyBadger's comment, " A CTE is executed when it is called in the following query. So when you do select * from cte ... is when the cte is executed (the whole cte)".. I didnt know this was so, I assumed it was executed first like like inserting into a TEMP table.

Comment: Updated answer with example.. but i am not able to understand your comment

Comment: @KannanKandasamy very nice example to explain the concept. However, in this case the filtering attribute is the result of a function (`rank`) so can't be indexed (at least not in a cte).

Comment: A CTE is another kind of subquery. CTEs and subqueries are almost the same thing with a could notable differences (e.g. subqueries can be correlated, CTEs can be recursive, etc). 

Both subqueries and CTEs (and views for that matter) can be expanded  to utilize underlying indexes .

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `RANK()` which you are calculating in your cte it must sort all the data by `t.ActionID`. Sorting is a blocking operation: the entire input must be processed before a single row is output.

So in this case whether you select any five rows, or if you take the five that sorted to the top of the pile is probably irrelevant.

Comment: If `t.ActionID` is indexed, no sorting needs to be performed.